# new-service powershell from a basic .exe 2012

Tags: powershell, windows-services

This can't possibly be so difficult to find...but it is! It seems once a year I want to create a windows service from a pre-compiled .exe program. Every-time I end up searching to try and remember what I forgot.

Now I see there is a "new-service" cmdlet shipping with powershell. GREAT! Except the binpath is clearly not supposed to be the path to the actual .exe you want to launch. :(

Can someone please tell me the simple, modern way to do this?

**-Edit--**

For the record, I'm aware of how to do this using srvany.exe or instsrv.exe...I'm just looking for the modern 2012 way (if one exists).

Comment: new-service creates a system of prompts where it first asks for the service name, then asks for the binpath. I've followed the prompts and created a new service which points directly at the .exe file I want to execute. Once I try to run the service I get "Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."

Comment: Here is the old msft documentation. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that it cannot be any executable.

It needs to have a service entry point, e.g. `OnStart`. See here:

[Error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673545/error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request)

Comment: that is exactly right, just microsoft used to have the open service wrappers srvany.exe and intrsrv.exe. I figured they would have something new.