# Im getting Error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create window service which sends mail to me when specific type of file came in the folder.While running the service i'm getting error like **'Error 1053- the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion. Please help me to resolve this error.'** I will be more thankful for you.

I have written code as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Timers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace DUP1
{
    class BrlCode
    {
        public void brlCount()
        {
            String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"H:\\EDI", "*.brl", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                var clientDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("clientDomain");
                var from = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("from");
                var to = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("to");
                MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(from, to);
                mm.Body = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("body");
                mm.Subject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("subject2");
                int leng = files.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                    String sep = "   |  ";

                    String Body1 = string.Join(sep, files, 0, leng);
                    mm.Body = Body1;

                }

                var smtp1 = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("clientDomain"));
                smtp1.Port = 25;

                //setting default credentials

                smtp1.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                smtp1.EnableSsl = false;
                smtp1.Send(mm);

            }
        }
    }

}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Timers;

namespace DUP1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        private Timer timer1 = null;

        public Service1()
        {
            this.OnStart(null);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer1 = new Timer();
            this.timer1.Interval = 540000;
            //Log("Service Started successfully");
            BrlCode bc = new BrlCode();

            bc.brlCount();
        }
        }


    }
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;



namespace DUP1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 

                new Service1() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
            Console.Write("yahoo");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>

  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="dipsk4@gmail.com" />

    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>

    <add key="clientDomain" value="mail.allstate.com"/>
    <add key="directory" value="H:\\"/>
    <add key="from"  value="dipsk4@gmail.com"/>
    <add key="to"  value="dipsk4@gmail.com"/>
    <add key="body"  value="01 .lnr files has been received"/>
    <add key="subject1" value="LNR files"/>
    <add key="subject2" value="BRL files"/>
    <add key="subject3" value="DUP files"/>
    <add key="attachment"  value="H:\\deep.txt"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: See question over there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673545/error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You should try offloading the work done by BrlCode in a different thread so that OnStart can return as fast as possible.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
  timer1 = new Timer();
  this.timer1.Interval = 540000;

  //Log("Service Started successfully");

  Task.Run(() => 
  {
    BrlCode bc = new BrlCode();
    bc.brlCount();
  });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? Do you still get the error?

Comment: Now that error is not coming but service is not giving any output as "not sending mail " as expected.

Comment: So this is progress :) The answer to your question regarding Error 1053 has been answered.

Comment: still code is not workingg for sending the mail. Please some one suggest me the error in my code why it is not sending the mail. whats going wrong in this code.

Comment: If the Error 1053 does not appear anymore, please mark the answer as accept. Then ask a new question regarding the mail issue so that it can be more visible; you are going to get more answers that way. And users looking for a similar issue will be able to find potential answers :) Everyone will benefit from it.