# Service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm very new at programming. 
I had to develop a Windows Service, which installs just fine in my computer.
We installed it on a PC with Windows 7 32-bits (I have Windows 10 x64) and when tried to start it the following error shows up:

> Windows could not start the Service1 service on local Computer
>
> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control
>   request in a timely fashion

I had this error before, but it took like 30 seconds of trying to start it to appear. This shows up pretty quickly.

Since it starts just fine on my computer, and on the ones from testing, could it be related to the OS? Could it be because of framework or something? I developed the service for Framework 4.5.2

Or could it be that the client has set up a timeout pretty low for the services?

```
public Service1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void Init()
{
    Logger.Configure(); 
    this.timer.Interval = 20000;
    this.timer.Elapsed += this.TimerElapsed;
    this.timer.Start();
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    this.Init();

    Logger.LogInfo("The Service1 has started.");
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    try
    {
        Logger.LogInfo("The Service1 has Stopped");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogException(ex);
    }
}

private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    this.timer.Stop();
    this.LoggerStart();
    this.timer.Start();
}
```

this.LoggerStart() just put some data in the log file.
Is there something wrong in the way that I'm starting the service? I don't understand what could be happening since it works fine at the office. 
Sorry for my poor english and please bear in mind that I'm VERY new at this. 
Thanks.

Comment: I think you would need to call Init on a newly spawned Thread as the service Start method may not be able to finish if Init() never returns - causing it to hang.

Comment: Could it be that `Logger.Configure();` throws an exception? I've seen this message when an unhandled exception occurs in the `OnStart`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1673545/397817 service, same error, also involves a timer. Does it help?

Comment: *"The service did not respond"* This general error message is hiding the actual error and that's why you can't make progress. Check your Windows Events to see if it's throwing an exception. Otherwise try running your Logger directly, using a console application. A number of things can cause this problem, e.g. running on the wrong framework or wrong architecture (try building your assembly for any CPU).

Comment: @derloopkat apparently they are running it on the right framework. I built it for any CPU. I'm gonna ask them to check Windows Events. Thank you!