# Service not starting up

Tags: c#, .net-core, service, kestrel

This is not a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931923/service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-timely-fashion), as I already attempted the recommended solutions in there.

I've been trying to start my C#/.netCore 3.0/Kestrel as a service.

After struggling to get my app to start as a service, I followed these [instructions](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2019/10/15/windowsservice/) to create a new exe, with the same result.

After publishing, and adding the service, and trying to start the service from either cmd, powershell, or the service interface, I am prompted with the following message :

> Windows could not start the SomeWorker service on Local Computer.
>   Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control
>   request in a timely fashion.

On investigating the system event log, I only see a generic :

> The myWorker service failed to start due to the following error: 
>   The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

When I run the exe/console, it starts up fine without any problems.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(
                options => options.AddFilter<EventLogLoggerProvider>(level => level >= LogLevel.Information))
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>()
                    .Configure<EventLogSettings>(config =>
                    {
                        config.LogName = "Sample Service";
                        config.SourceName = "Sample Service Source";
                    });
            }).UseWindowsService();
}


public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically, the windows service OnStart event should complete within 30seconds. I am not sure it still holds true in the .NET Core world. Are you doing some _heavy_ work during the startup?

Comment: @Thangadurai. Not at all. This was my first instinct as well. Everything I have in the solution, is what you see in the code above. I've even tried increasing the timeout via regedit, but still receive the same result.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `System.Diagnostic.Debugger.Break` call in somewhere to see if you can get a debug session going when it starts?

Comment: I tried the same example that you have posted. I haven't changed anything, but it works for me and I am able to see the log messages in the Event Viewer. Can you check on which user account or service account your service is created/running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was that Visual Studio was not set to deploy the service as self-contained.

After setting this in the project's properties, everything worked fine.

Comment: how did you make the service as self-contained?

Comment: @franva I can't recall the exact way now, and I don't have a visual studio close by to check, but when you right click, publish, there should be an option to setup a self contained .net core publish

Comment: I'm using VS2019 after clicking Publish, there are 4 options: Azure, Docker, Folder and Import Profile. I guess I need some dig in. thanks :)

Comment: @Franva: use Folder and then click on the edit button to configure the profile.

Comment: @WynDiesel: I found this option but it doesn't solve the problem. I still get the error 1053. I use VS2019 but I also tried to publish via dotnet.exe in the console.

Comment: @Sebastian. Have you checked the system event logs? That gave me a clear indication of what the actual problem was. I would also recommend rather starting your own post, as no-one but me will be answering your questions if you post it here.

Comment: hi @Sebastian I solved my problem. I missed 2 things. 1. .UseWindowsService(), 2. install a nuget package. I found both on the Microsoft doc website.

Comment: *This answer finally gives the hint for my solution*. I have VS 2019 and 2022 pro installed. Before installing VS 2022 I built my deployment using VS 2019 & everything works fine. Therefore I was deploying using VS 2019 build. I am not sure how VS 2019 build is broken suddenly, also not sure VS 2019 self-contained build is having issues after installing VS 2022. When I build same proj with VS 2022 everything works fine. In my observation files produced by VS 2019 are diff from VS 2022 build.      My project was on 3.1 and I upgraded the packages from 3.x to 6.x without changing .net core ver.

Answer (score 6):

There are some points to verify.

1. Intall Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices and use it in your project. You can use some log package like Serilog, but it is optional.

[image]

2. Configure the publish with your options. Important to check **ReadyToRun** and Self-contained.

[image]

Comment: #1 was an issue for me, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this will help, I had the same problem.  It came down to this in my CreateHostBuilder method:

```
    host.ConfigureAppConfiguration(
        (hostContext, config) =>
        {
            config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true);
        }
    );
```

It turns out the above is no longer necessary as calling CreateDefaultBuilder will set the base path and add appsettings.json.  Here is what my CreateHostBuilder now looks like (and it works fine):

```
        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    .Build();
                var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                    .CreateLogger();
                loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(logger, dispose: true);
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<SrtLmcoMaximoSyncWorker>();
            });
        return host;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the issue that I faced:

I wanted a .net core 6 Windows Service.  So I create a Project using the Background Worker template which appears to run fine in Visual Studio.  However, when the project was published and run as a service on Windows Server, the service would fail to start.  Checking the event log showed no exceptions.

This issue is that a Background worker project will not run as-is as a Windows Service.  It's close, but you must add this code to ensure it actually works with the Windows Service Manager:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
 .UseWindowsService(options =>
 {
     options.ServiceName = "Your Service Name";
 })
```

Also, ensure you add Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices lib to your project.

[Full Windows Service Walkthrough project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service?pivots=dotnet-6-0)